# Android Time Structures

Tags: android, datetime, time

I have a class that I would like to store specific times in. The times will be used to schedule tasks to execute. And right now I'm working with the `Time` class from `android.text.format`, but this isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

I can create time stamps, but it pads it with the date, timezone, etc.

```
Time startTime = new Time();
startTime.setToNow();

tvConsole.setText(startTime.toString());  // just to view it in the emulator
```

and the results:

```
20101208T162807America/New_York(3,341,-18000,0,1291843687)
```

I do not need all of this information, nor do I want it. Is there any way to just access the hh/mm/ss members? I am aware I can set just time of the object, but then it displays as some date in 1970... and I can't retrieve just the time members. Is there another class I am not aware of that I can do this with?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some looking around I found what I was looking for. The answer is the `Calendar` class. I included a sample of code below.

```
DateFormat formatTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(); // set the format type
Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance(); // this line will store the current time
startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);     // modify the time to something
startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 40);

if (startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY == 10)   // example of accessing data member
    tvConsole.setText(formatTime.format(startTime.getTime()));  // display
```

This will display: `10:30:40 PM`

Answer (score 3):

Use Time fields:

```
Time startTime = new Time();
startTime.setToNow();

startTime.hour
startTime.minute
startTime.second
```

If you just need a displayable time (like "1:59pm"), then you can use DateUtils.

```
//Look at the different FORMAT_ flags on DateUtils.
String s = DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, startTime.toMillis(true),  
                                    DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME);
```

Comment: can't do that. `startTime.hour` is not a method to retrieve the hour data member.

Comment: It's there since API level 3 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html. Actually it's just a public int variable, not a method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the native format for time:

```
Time startTime = new Time();
startTime.setToNow();

tvConsole.setText(startTime.format("%I:%M %P"));  // just to view it in the emulator
```

All the variables that you can use are listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php